# The function f: Z x Z -> ZxZ defined by the formula f(m,n) = (5m+4n, 4m+3n) is bijective. Then find its inverse.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am not getting how to prove its bijection. My textbook says I need to manipulate it such that, $(x,y) = f(m,n)$ to $f(x,y) =(m,n)$.

All I get is $(5x+4y, 4x+3y) = (5m+4n, 4m+3n)$

And then I find the inverse by making the system of equations equal to $m$ and $n$, such that-

$(m, n) = (5x+4y, 4x+3y)$

$5x+4y = m \rightarrow x  = \frac{m-4n}{5}, 4x+3y = n \rightarrow y = \frac{n-4m}{3}$

Then, $(x, y) = (\frac{m-4n}{5}, \frac{n-4m}{3})$

So, $f^{-1} (m, n) = (\frac{x-4y}{5}, \frac{y-4x}{3})$

Comment: I'm not sure how the step
$$
5x+4y =m \implies x = (m-4n)/5
$$
is supposed to work.  Did you replace $y$ with $n$???

Comment: "(5x+4y, 4x+3y) = (5m+4n, 4m+3n)"?? I'm afraid you're misinterpreting something here. This claim is the same as saying that $x=m$ and $y=n$, but that's certainly not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Another description of $f$: $f(x,y)$ is precisely the column vector you obtain when you multiply the colummn vector $(x,y)$ by the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 5&4\\4&3\end{bmatrix}$ on the left. The inverse is obtained by multiplying by $A^{-1}$ on the left. I'll let you calculate $A^{-1}$ by yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Even though the matrix is simple enough that I can find the inverse of it, I have not formally studied matrices. Can you tell me why that logic works?

Comment: @ChocolateAndMath Basically, the same formula for $f$ makes sense with $\mathbb{R}$ in place of $\mathbb{Z}$, and in this case the transformation $f$ is what is called "linear": $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ and $f(\lambda x)=\lambda f(x)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. It's standard fact that linear transformations are determined by matrices, and the matrix associated with $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of the matrix associated with $f$. Of course, one has to go back to $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$, but that's not a real problem in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your current answer is incorrect.  Here's a way to go about it:
$$
x = 5m + 4n \implies m = \frac{x - 4n}{5}
$$
Now, substitute this into the next equation
$$
y = 4m + 3n = 4 \frac{x - 4n}{5} + 3n \implies\\
y = -\frac{1}{5}n + \frac 45 x
$$
now, solve this equation for $n$, then substitute into $m = \frac{x-4n}{5}$.  Then, you'll have a formula for the "inputs" $m,n$ in terms of the "outputs" $x,y$, which is what you're looking for.

---

In particular, we find
$$
y = -\frac{1}{5}n + \frac 45 x \implies\\
n = 4 x - 5y 
$$
Similarly, we have
$$
m = \frac{x-4n}{5} = \frac{x - 4(4 x - 5y )}{5} = -3x + 5y
$$
So, the formula for our inverse is 
$$
f(x,y) = (-3x + 5y, 4x - 5y)
$$

Comment: I see what you're saying with my logic as well as substitution. So, this is what I am getting with substitution -

x = 5m+4n
m = (x-4n)/5 ----- eq. 1

y = 4m +3n 
n = (y-4m)/3
(on putting in eq. 1, we get) - 

n = (y-4((x-4n)/5))/3

I'm not sure if this is the answer or what to do next.

Comment: See my latest edit, which includes a correction to a previous mistake and a full answer.